# AngularJS failed to wireup an instance of controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm creating a simpleApp using angularJS, unfortunately I have no idea about why it keeps showing blank. I guess AngularJS has failed to glue my controller & view.

Index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="simpleApp">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-view="">
        </div>
        
        <script src="/app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
        <script src="/app/services/customerService.js"></script>
        <script src="/app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

App.js

```js
var app = angular.module("simpleApp", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", { controller: "simpleController", templateUrl: "/app/partials/view1.html" })
        .when("/view2", { controller: "simpleController", templateUrl: "/app/partials/view2.html" })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo: "/" });
});
```

Controllers.js

```js
app.controller("simpleController", function($scope) {
    $scope.customers = [
        { Name: "Dave Jones",  City: "Phoenix" }
        , { Name: "Jamie Riley", City: "Atlanta" }
        , { Name: "Heedy Walhin", City: "Chandler" }
        , { Name: "Thomas Winter", City: "Seattle" }
    ];
});
```

View1.html

```html
<div>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="filter.name"/>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers | filter: filter.name | orderBy: 'Name'">
            {{ cust.Name | uppercase }} - {{ cust.City | lowercase }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br/>
    Customer Name:
    <br/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.Name"/>
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="newCustomer.City"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" data-ng-click="addNewCustomer"/>
    <a href="#/view2">View 2</a>
</div>
```

View2.html

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li data-ng-repeat="cust in customers">
            {{ cust.Name | lowercase }} - {{ cust.City | upppercase }}
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

any idea?

Comment: where's your ui-view directive ?

Comment: right there, in the index.html

Comment: Your scripts are included in your HTML page in the wrong (reverse) order, no? I would expect AngularJS to be included first, then app, then your service, and finally your controllers.

Comment: I did try to change the order of declaration for the scripts 100k times, but it doesn't help

Comment: also, if you want to use the "standard" $routeProvider, you need the `ngRoute` module as a dependency to your module: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: It may not be your only problem, but you definitely should be loading the scripts in the correct order so the references are available.

Comment: having angular-route.js included into the index.html as following order  but it doesn't work

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/app/services/customerService.js"></script>

Answer (score 2):

The ng-route module is not part of the core angular.js file, you need to include it separately. Also the order of js files need to be changed

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="/app/app.js"></script>
<script src="/app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="/app/services/customerService.js"></script>
```

then

```
var app = angular.module("simpleApp", ['ngRoute']);
```

Also you have got the filter name `uppercase` wrong

```
{{ cust.Name | lowercase }} - {{ cust.City | uppercase }}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ve7yuear/)

Comment: DO yourself a favour and use [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router)

Comment: ui-router is excellent, but it's not necessary until it's necessary.

Comment: @Bonatoc I have used it... and it is great... but in this case the OP is using ng-route and I was just pointing out the problem

Comment: @ArunPJohny: I have just included it into the index.html but it still doesn't work

Comment: @guruvn you also have a spelling issue in `uppercase`.. you have `upppercase`

Comment: @guruvn check your browser console to see whether there are any errors

Comment: it was the path issue. (cry)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're missing a reference to the controller on your index.

Something like:

`<body ng-controller="simpleController">`

Should get your index page going.

Your routing configuration looks fine, but those routes are not affecting the actual index page. Those routes would load your views into an ng-view directive.

Comment: The controller was added into the module in controllers.js. And the module itself was referenced in the index.html by data-ng-app="simpleApp". So is it possible for you to be more detail about how the reference should be missing?

Comment: I'm sorry about the lack of details. I've just added a bit of code.

Comment: hmm... we should not need to specify the ng-controller in the body tag right. Because we have already configured it in the app.js

Comment: That is correct when using the ng-view directive, which I see has been added. And adding the new ngRoute module dependency should have solved your problem.

Comment: Also, please use the browser's debugging console to make sure you're not getting any errors while trying to load the partials.

Comment: the ng-Route directed was included in the app.js, but it doesn't help. the application is not working at all

Answer (score 0):

it was the path issue. I did miss "." when referencing to all javascript in the index.html file

The following code snippet should fix the issue

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="./app/app.js"></script>
<script src="./app/controllers/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="./app/services/customerService.js"></script>
```